# The product of components in the partition of a number.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, generating-functions, integer-partitions

> Let $f(n,k)$ be the sum of expressions of the form $x_1 \cdot x_2 \cdot \ldots \cdot x_k$, where the sum counts over all solutions of the equation $x_1 + \ldots + x_k = n$ in natural numbers. Find closed-form for the generating function $S_k(z) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} f(n,k) x^n$ and for $f(n,k)$.

Of course, if we have $ x_1 \cdot x_2 \cdot \ldots \cdot x_k $, then no $x$ can be zero, so
we actually have partitions $ x_1 + \ldots + x_k = n $ into components $ >0 $. From stars and bars, I know that there are $ \binom{n-1}{k-1} $ such partitions. How can I continue?

Comment: we're not considering the order of the $x_k$s right?

Comment: We do, $2+1$ is different from $1+2$ as $x_1 \neq x_2$. So $f(3,2)=2\cdot1 + 1\cdot2$.

Comment: notice: if we have a set of terms $x_1 z^{x_1}, x_2 z^{x_2}, ..., x_n z^{x_n}$, their product will be $x_1\cdot x_2 \cdot ... \cdot x_n z^{x_1+x_2+...+x_n}$

Comment: These are usually called integer compositions (where (2,1) and (1,2) are distinct examples) in contrast to integer partitions (where (2,1) and (1,2) correspond to the same partition).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that, when multiplying polynomials (or power series), the coefficients get multiplied while the exponents get added. This means that if we represent a set of integers as a sum of terms of the form $az^a$, the product of two such sums can be considered as a sum of all terms of the form $a_a a_b z^{a_a+a_b}$, with $a_a$ from the first set and $a_b$ from the second set.

In order to represent that we may use any integers to construct the sums and products we are studying, let's define $I(z) = \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} iz^i = 0z^0 + 1z^1 + 2z^2 + ...$

Let's look at the behaviour of $I(z)^k$:

This power of a power series can be seen as a sum of powers, where the coefficient of the nth power of z is of the form $x_{1,1}x_{1,2}...x_{1,k}+x_{2,1}x_{2,2}...x_{2,k} + ... +x_{\binom{n-1}{k-1},1}x_{\binom{n-1}{k-1},2}...x_{\binom{n-1}{k-1},k}$

so $S_k(z) = I(z)^k$

Now we have to find a closed form for $I(z)$, but this is trivial if we notice that each term of the series is $az^a = z(az^{a-1}) = z \frac{d}{dz} z^a$, so $I(z) = z \frac{d}{dz} (1+z+z^2+...) = z \frac{d}{dz}\frac{1}{1-z} = \frac{z}{(1-z)^2}$

We get that $S_k(z) = \frac{z^k}{(1-z)^{2k}}$

A study of the derivatives of $S_k(z)$ will probably give you an easier way to find $f(n,k)$.

Comment: Then $f(n,k)=\binom{n+k-1}{2k-1}$. Thanks a lot.